# PHP - Determine if one more more options are selected

Tags: php

I'm trying to use PHP to determine if one or more options are selected.

I have this code that works for a singular item:

```
if (isset($_POST['option43'])) {
  if (isset($_POST['option41'])) {
    $sql .= " mysql string";
  } else {  
    $sql .= " my other sql string";
   }
}
```

But when I try to add || to include another item, the PHP fails to load:

```
if (isset($_POST['option43'])) {
  if (isset($_POST['option41'] || isset($_POST['option42']))) {
    $sql .= " mysql string";
  } else {  
    $sql .= " my other sql string";
}
}
```

Can anyone help me understand how to make this work?

Here is the HTML:

```
                            <tr>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" name="option41" value="bm" />bm </td>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" name="option42" value="Tv" />tv </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" name="option43" value="hp" />hp </td>
                            </tr>
```

Basically I'm trying to write:

IF option 43 is checked, THIS is the sql
but if option 41 or 42 is checked, THIS is the sql

thanks

Comment: Please show your HTML code as well, otherwise it's very hard to tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found your issue: You made a mistake in the bracketing of the `if` condition. Change your `if` condition to block as in the below code. It may be helpful.

```
if (isset($_POST['option43'])) {
  if (isset($_POST['option41']) || isset($_POST['option42'])) {
    $sql .= " mysql string";
  } else {  
    $sql .= " my other sql string";
}
}
```

Your mistake is that in your `if` you're checking for `$_POST['option41']`, but you have not completed your `isset` function bracket after checking one condition in same your are checking for other option. Please try the above code.

Comment: YES!  OMG thank you.  One little error can screw up the whole thing and I can spend hours trying to figure out where I have a misplaced ().  Thank you so much.  I tried to upvote your answer, but this account doesn't have a high enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_POST['option43']) && !isset($_POST['option41']) && !isset($_POST['option42'])) {
   $sql .= " my sql string";
}elseif(isset($_POST['option43']) && (isset($_POST['option41']) || isset($_POST['option42']))){
   $sql .= " my other sql string";
}
```